# How to establish communication between service-worker and main in Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, communication

I am trying to build continuous communication between `service-worker.js` and `main.js` in order to post what data is received from an API to Google Documents, but I can't figure out how to do it using Manifest V3. The first problem I've encountered is registering the `service-worker` like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('/sw.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Service worker registered:', registration);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error registering service worker:', error);
            });
    });
}
```

but it always catches the error. From what I've understood, Manifest V3 registers the SW-s internally so I don't need to worry about registration.

I've tried using `Workbox` but I can't simply import it with `importScripts` and working with `workbox-cli` is too complex and in the end, I think is unnecessary.

Edit: here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"author": "",

"permissions": ["storage", "identity", "tabs", "activeTab"],
"host_permissions": [
    "https://*.docs.google.com/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
],
"background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js",
    "type": "module"
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.docs.google.com/*", "<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["main.js", "recorder.js"]
    }
],

"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "",
    "api_key": "",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "profile"
    ],
    "discovery_docs": ["https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"]
},
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' ; object-src 'self'"
},
"manifest_version": 3
```

and in main.js has a check for registration

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
    if (registrations.length > 0) {
        console.log('Registered Service Workers:');
        for (let i = 0; i < registrations.length; i++) {
            console.log(registrations[i]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Registering service worker');

        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('./service-worker.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Service worker registered:', registration);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
            });
    }
});
```

All my files are in the same directory.

Comment: I've updated the post, I only have 3 files my manifest, sw and main.js all in the same directory

Comment: Content scripts don't have direct access to the extension's origin and its service worker, so indeed the only solution is to use [`chrome` messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Hmm, I think that will be a problem. At some point in my extension, I will need to get some data from an API and send  messages to service-worker. How could I do that with chrome messaging?

Comment: You'll simply send the data in a message.